# [ ][ ] and if-statement not working in code

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, 2d

I have some problems in the below code regarding the if-statement and possibly the 2D arrays, which I state below:

```
int[][]image =
    {
        {0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0},
        {0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0},
        {0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0},
        {2,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,2},
        {0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0},
        {0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0},
        {0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0},
        {0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}//assume this rectangular image
    };  

    int[][]smooth = new int[image.length][image[0].length]; //new array equal to image[][]
```

Notice image[][]. It is a 2D array composed of a series of numbers. Below it, I initialize an identical array: smooth[][]. Each of smooth[][]'s elements are replaced with the numerical average of the 8 bordering elements plus itself.

The edge elements in smooth[][] (elements on outside border of array) should not be changed.

I attempt to do this with if-statements, but am only half successful. The numbers on the top and left borders do not change (r == 0 || c == 0), but any number on the bottom or right border will change to become the average value.

```
    //compute the smoothed value of non-edge locations in smooth[][]

    for(int r=0; r<image.length-1; r++)     
    {// x-coordinate of element

    for(int c=0; c<image[r].length-1; c++)      
    { //y-coordinate of element

    int sum1 = 0;//sum of each element's 8 bordering elements and itself



    if(r == 0 || c == 0 || r == (image[c].length) || c == (image[r].length))
        smooth[r][c] = image[r][c]; 

    else        
    {

        sum1 = image[r-1][c-1] + image[r-1][c] + image[r-1][c+1]    
        + image[r][c-1] + image[r][c] + image[r][c+1] +image[r+1][c-1] 
        + image[r+1][c] + image[r+1][c+1];

        smooth[r][c]= sum1 / 9; //average of considered elements becomes new elements
```

Comment: What do you think, can index of last element in array be equal with its length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are stopping you processing too early for your `if` statements to catch the right and bottom border cases.  Your `for` loop conditions:

```
for(int r=0; r<image.length-1; r++)     
{// x-coordinate of element

    for(int c=0; c<image[r].length-1; c++)      
    { //y-coordinate of element
```

stop processing before the right column or bottom row is reached.  The default value of `0` happens to match the average value that would be there because of all the zeros.

Let your `if` statement catch the border cases by changing your `for` loop conditions to include the right and bottom border cases -- don't subtract `1` from the length.

```
for(int r=0; r<image.length; r++)     
{// x-coordinate of element

    for(int c=0; c<image[r].length; c++)      
    { //y-coordinate of element
```

But you must test for your "on the right" and "on the bottom" conditions correctly.  Subtract one from the `length`s of the arrays here.

```
if(r == 0 || c == 0 || r == (image[c].length - 1) || c == (image[r].length - 1))
    smooth[r][c] = image[r][c];
```

Comment: If I don't subtract a 1 in the for-loops, I receive a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Comment: Then please apply the second fix in the `if` condition that will cover the border cases properly.  If it's a border square, then you won't perform the average processing, which would otherwise run off the edge giving the AIOOBE.

Comment: I originally thought I did, but I must have missed part of your answer because I c/p'd it and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It would seem the issue is here

```
if(r == 0 || c == 0 || r == (image[c].length) || c == (image[r].length))
    smooth[r][c] = image[r][c];
```

This is where you are saying if the cell is an edge `(r == 0 || c == 0 || ...)` but you've made a small mistake. Remember than the last element is the length minus one, e.g., `(... r == (image[c].length - 1) || c == (image[r].length - 1))`.

Cool bonus visual:

```
         (array.length) is this ─┐ (notice it doesn't exist)
  (array.length - 1) is this ─┐  │
                              v  v
     array | [x] [x] [x] [x] [x]
element is | 1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th
  index is |  0   1   2   3   4
```

> Edit: The below is all true but I was thrown off by your use of the word equal but moreso my hasty reading. Because it is true and correct I will leave it, but it is irrelevant to this question.

```
int[][]smooth = new int[image.length][image[0].length]; //new array equal to image[][]
```

This is not creating a new array equal to it, it's creating a new array with the same size. It initializes all the elements in the new array to 0 instead of what you think it's doing. Use some `for` loops of `System.arraycopy()` to make a copy correctly.